# Which Doctor Who (classic) episodes aren't available today?

Tags: doctor-who

It's popular that BBC has lost many Doctor Who (classic) episodes. Also, some of episodes were recuperated using fans' tapes.

Which Doctor Who (classic) episodes aren't available today? I am talking about original episodes here. I know fans have already created new episodes based on those stories.

Comment: The exact list of missing serials is just a Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_missing_episodes#List_of_missing_episodes, but I hope my answer to that question is more valuable than a mere list.